# How to find what objects a given CLSID supports

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, com, clsidfromprogid

**Question:**

- Based on a [**CLSID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691424.aspx), how can I find out what **objects** (or interfaces) it **supports** for `IClassFactory::CreateInstance`

**Note:**

- Currently **using** [**CLSIDFromProgID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688386(VS.85).aspx) to obtain CLSID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use OleView.

But if you want to do this programatically then you could use the method that OleView uses.

OleView achieves this by just iterating through all the interfaces declared in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface and then calling QueryInterface for each of them.